# Syntax to retrieve a column from a cell to use in a formula?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to map a column in a financial report with a table.

Right now my formula searches the "E:E" column. However instead of using "E:E" which is hardcoded I want to let users change the column by mapping it in a table. The red square marks the cell I want to retrieve the column from.

[image]

How can I make it so that instead of using "E:E" it retrieves the column to search for in the cell "TeamColumn"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [`INDIRECT` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/151323).  This function parses a string and returns the reference to the cell(s) that string describes.  In this case, assuming the letter `E` is in cell `A1`, your formula would be

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'Raw Data'!" & A1 & ":" & A1), "")
```